# object equals method being == and shallow copy

Tags: java

I have

```
Object o = new Object()
o == o.clone(); //I understand this should be false since it's different two arraylist pointing to the same object right?
o.equals(o.clone())  //it's true if it's shallow copy since pointing at the same one
```

here equals isn't ==, it should be comparing hash code right? since it's object.
source: [equals method usage in string and list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53661319/equals-method-usage-in-string-and-list)

but on my notes it says the equal method means == here.

is my notes wrong?

my note says the object class has aclone() method but it has an empty implementation,
and an object of the object class is not allowed to invoke this method because of this reason.

Can someone please explain this b etter? I think I misunderstanding something

Comment: @Krease So according to the link equals mean == but I learnt equals in objects compare hashcode but == means checking the value no?

Comment: `equals` doesn't *"mean"* `==`. `equals` is just a method to enable objects to compare themselves with other objects. Its *default implementation* (i.e. `Object.equals(Object)`) is to check for *identity* (i.e. `==`).

Comment: *"here equals [...] should be comparing hash code right?"* No, `equals()` doesn't compare hash codes. It doesn't what you coded it to do, assuming you implemented the method on your class. With `Object` class, `equals()` is implemented to use `==`, so for `Object` (and any class without `equals()` implementation, `equals()` is the same as `==`, but it (should) never compare hash codes.

Answer (score 1):

`==` compares object reference - are they the exact same memory reference. `equals` is a method implemented per class, typically to do more useful comparison (like if two strings contain the same characters, or if two lists contain the same content).

However, the default implementation in `Object` simply falls back to doing an `==` comparison, so for instances of that class, there is no difference.

Comment: that's the opposite of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53661319/equals-method-usage-in-string-and-list.....

Comment: What? That answer is incorrect about `hashCode` (I've commented on it, and expect it will be fixed soon) - comparing `hashCode` values is NOT the default implementation of `equals`, and should NEVER be the implementation of `equals` - it is possible to have multiple non-equal objects with the same result for `hashCode`. That said, whenever overriding `equals`,  you should always override `hashCode` so that objects that **are equal** generate the same hash.  Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java) as a primer.

Comment: I've added my own answer to your other question, hope it proves useful in explaining this concept.

Answer (score 0):

- `==` checks *object identity* in the context of object references.

  ```
  Foo f1 = new Foo();
  Foo f2 = f1; // Both f1 and f2 refer to the same object.
  // f1 == f2 returns true
  Foo f3 = new Foo(); // A second instance of Foo is created
  // f1 == f3 returns false
  ```

  Only in the context of primitive data types (`boolean`, `byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `char`, `float` and `double`) `==` checks for value.<sup>1</sup>
- The `equals` method is nothing more than a method to enable objects to compare themselves with other objects. The documentation of `equals` sets requirements to how the programmer should implement the method, but technically the programmer *could* do anything he wants.

  The implementation of `Object.equals(Object)` is simply `return this == obj)`.
- The `equals` method **should never rely on nor call `hashCode()`**, since it's possible that two objects which are considered unequal according to `equals` could have the same hash code. The only requirement of `hashCode` is the other way around: that it must return the same hash code for all object considered equal by means of the `equals` method.

---

<sup>1</sup> As Andreas already mentioned in the comments – technically `==` always checks value. This also counts for object references, since object references themselves are values.

Comment: Technically, `==` always checks for value, its just that if the value is a reference, it is the reference value (object identity) that is being checked.

Comment: @Andreas You're right, just as Java is always pass by value. I'll add that to my answer.